# Validation set in access breaks the program

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, vba

The program breaks and displays this message once I input the wrong amount of numbers in a textbox and submited the form.

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException'
>   occurred in System.Data.dll
>
> Additional information: One or more values are prohibited by the
>   validation rule 'Is Null Or Like "###########"' set for
>   'T_Jobs.Customer_Phone'.  Enter a value that the expression for this
>   field can accept."

I have connected visual basic to access using the data source connecting wizard. I want the program to display a message saying "**input 11 numbers**" instead of it breaking.

Comment: I'd validate the data *before* sending it to access.

Comment: Is it possible to set the number of digits i want for a text box?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a validation function

```
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    If IsValidForm() Then
        ' Save the Record
        ' This line takes all the input from the boxes from adding a New job form, And puts it into 
        ' corresponding boxes in the main menu = because only those boxes  
        ' are connected to the database
        ' It uses the data adapter from form1
        Form1.T_JobsTableAdapter.Insert(Me.TextBox2.Text, M, e.TextBox3.Text, Me.TextBox4.Text,
                                           Me.TextBox5.Text, Me.TextBox6.Text, Me.TextBox7.Text, Me.TextBox8.Text)

        'This line updates the table Jobs dataset with the information in the boxes in main menu
        'The DataSet passes on the collected data to the database
        Form1.T_JobsTableAdapter.Fill(Form1.JobsDBDataSet.T_Jobs)
        MsgBox("Record added successfully")

        ' These lines clear the textboxes so that next job can be added
        TextBox2.Text = ""
        TextBox3.Text = ""
        TextBox4.Text = ""
        TextBox5.Text = ""
        TextBox6.Text = ""
        TextBox7.Text = ""
        TextBox8.Text = ""
    End If
End Sub

Private Function IsValidForm() As Boolean
    Dim msg As String = String.Empty

    ' Ensure that a Valid Vehicle Model was entered
    If TextBox3.Text = "" Then
        '  MsgBox("Please fill in Car Model", MsgBoxStyle.Information)
        msg += "Enter a Car Model" & vbCr
    End If

    ' Validate Date Received
    If Not IsDate(TextBox2.Text) Then
        msg += "Enter a valid Date Received" & vbCr
    End If

    ' Validate Date Due
    If Not IsDate(TextBox2.Text) Then
        msg += "Enter a valid  Date Due" & vbCr
    End If

    ' Validate Phone Number
    If Trim(TextBox8.Text) = "" Then
        ' NOTE I am not sure how you want to validate this phone number.
        ' You can do it with RegEx
        ' The Regular Expression tells VB to make sure that TextBox8 contains only
        ' Numbers 1 - 9 and only a length of 11. If it does not match, then
        ' display the validation message
         If Not System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(TextBox8.Text, "^[0-9]{11}$") Then
           msg += "Enter a Phone Number" & vbCr
         End If
End If

    If msg.Length > 0 Then
    MessageBox.Show("Please fix the following errors before continuing:" & Microsoft.VisualBasic.ControlChars.CrLf & msg,
                    Application.ProductName, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
        Return False
    Else
        Return True
    End If

End Function
```

Comment: Lovely idea but now i cannot close the program without putting the numbers in. Plus even when i input the numbers the message still pops up and i cant do anythig

Comment: @KamilLazarowicz You can do additional validation as needed. This is just one example of one way that you can validate that one field. There are a lot of options that you can take. I am more that willing to help in anyway that I can however we have not collaborated on the software that you are writing, other than what is listed above. I am not sure of all the requirements are for the software. I am just trying to help stop the error occurring if 11 numbers are typed into a textbox. If you could provide a little bit of code on your end, maybe I could help better.

Comment: sure but let me know which code in general do you need,

Comment: I need this validationg for a form where there are 8 different inputs. Once of them is a phone number which i want to limit to only 11 numbers. All the data is saved once a button is clicked and all coding is done under that button. I have generally connected my VB program to my access database using the built in wizard in VB

Comment: this is the code, it also vaildates the date format and that a specific textbox isnt empty

Comment: @KamilLazarowicz I edited the original code and added a Validation Function. You can add whatever you like to ensure that all the required fields are valid prior to the form saving. I hope this helps.

Comment: @KamilLazarowicz I am unable to comment on the answer below, so... You wrote that you want to ensure that one of the textboxes was only 11 numbers only. I have edited my above code, that includes validation for that as well

Answer (score 0):

this is the code for adding data, it also validates if a textbox isnt empty and if the date is in date format

```
            If TextBox3.Text = "" Then
        MsgBox("Please fill in Car Model", MsgBoxStyle.Information)

    Else

        'This checks if the Date Recieved and Date Due is in the correct format
        If IsDate(TextBox2.Text) And IsDate(TextBox6.Text) Then
            'This line takes all the input from the boxes from adding a new job form, and puts it into 
            'corresponding boxes in the main menu = because only those boxes  
            'are connected to the database
            'It uses the data adapter from form1
            Form1.T_JobsTableAdapter.Insert(Me.TextBox2.Text, Me.TextBox3.Text, Me.TextBox4.Text,
                                            Me.TextBox5.Text, Me.TextBox6.Text, Me.TextBox7.Text, Me.TextBox8.Text)

            'This line updates the table Jobs dataset with the information in the boxes in main menu
            'The dataset passes on the collected data to the database
            Form1.T_JobsTableAdapter.Fill(Form1.JobsDBDataSet.T_Jobs)
            MsgBox("Record added sucessfully")

            'These lines clear the textboxes so that next job can be added
            TextBox2.Text = ""
            TextBox3.Text = ""
            TextBox4.Text = ""
            TextBox5.Text = ""
            TextBox6.Text = ""
            TextBox7.Text = ""
            TextBox8.Text = ""

        Else
            MsgBox("Please ensure the Date Recieved and Date Due is in dd/mm/yyyy format", MsgBoxStyle.Information)

        End If

    End If
```

Comment: This is very helpful thankyou, works as it should. I want the number to be simply 11 numbers; ive restricted the textbox to only allow numbers on the key_press event, now i just need it to check if there are 11 numbers or no.